# How to present a nice looking frequency table from R in MS Word

Tags: r, ms-office

So, I copied this frequency table from R into an MS Word document:

```
   I A    I B   II A   II B   III  A  III A  III B   IV 
   128     73     61     59      1    166     86    463
```

How can I make it look nicer in the document? 
No Latex please, it should be written in an MS document.

Comment: Take a look at [Rmarkdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_docx.html)

Comment: Check this http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2013/06/create-word-documents-from-r-with-r2docx.html

Comment: Define "nicer". Possibly something like package stargazer offers what you are looking for?

Answer (score 4):

Using RStudio, you can easily create a markdown, which you can compile to a word document. To do so, go to file, create new, and select R mardown. Rstudio will allow you to select Word as output.

In addition to that, I suggest using knitr library and more specifically the kable function which gives a nice rendering of data frames (which you seem to be interested in).

### Edit: Added example of table rendering

Using a Rmarkdown and compiling it to word will give a text output, but using kable function from knitr with format "pandoc", will render a table exactly as it was created in Word.
The image below is a screenshot from the Word document generated thanks to the code:

````
```{r cars}
summary(cars)
knitr::kable(head(iris), format = "pandoc", caption = "Title of the table")
```
````

[image: Kable rendering]

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, I just tried the markdown but actually it just moves the table to MS word, just like when I copy the table from R to word. What I meant with nicer, was that I want it to look like a table you seen for example in presentations with rows and columns, not just "text".

Comment: I edited my answer to show the difference between the simple markdown and the table generated by knitr::kable.

Comment: Thanks for your edit, I' m definitely missing something because I can't make it work, but I'll search more and solve it.